# Line by Line Analysis of Algorithm with Early Return Statement

Tags: java, algorithm, search, analysis, asymptotic-complexity

I am attempting some homework for an algorithms class and I am running into a situation that is not described in the book. My task is to create an algorithm and perform a line by line analysis of `Sequential` or `Linear Search` to find element `k` in the array `A[p...r]`.

My algorithm is ridiculously simple:

```
1   for ct=1 to r
2       if A[ct] == k
3           return ct
4   return -1
```

Intuitively, I already know that this algorithm will perform in Θ(1) under optimal circumstances and Θ(n) under worst case but I'm having a little trouble performing the line by line analysis to prove that.

Here is what I have so far for my analysis (please note that the #s next to the constants and the j under tj is supposed to be subscript):

```
Line |  Algorithm     |  constants      |   time

1       for ct=1 to r           c1          tj+1    
2           if A[ct] = k        c2          tj
3              return ct        c3          1
4       return -1               c4          1
```

Adding up the constants by their complexity gives me:

```
c1(tj+1) + c2tj +c3 + c4 = tj(c1+ c2) + (c1 + c3 + c4) = tj(c) + c = tj
```

**Here is what is tripping me up...**

In all cases, Lines 3 and 4 will be performed just once which is why I listed them as constant time but in reality only one of them will ever be performed during a search. I know that for asymptotic notation that the constants don't really matter but it is bothering that my `tj(c1+ c2) + (c1 + c3 + c4)` statement includes the `c3 + c4` because I know it should really be something more like `c3 or c4`.

**Questions**

I'm able to plug in my T(n) appropriately so that T(1) = Θ(1) and T(n) = Θ(n) but I feel that I haven't accurately proved that.

- Can anyone weigh in on where my math may be incorrect?
- How are you supposed to evaluate early return statements within an algorithm?

Comment: The complexity is  O(r)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm able to plug in my T(n) appropriately so that T(1) = Θ(1) and T(n) = Θ(n) but I feel that I haven't accurately proved that.
>
> Can anyone weigh in on where my math may be incorrect?

I'm too late and I'm pretty sure you already know all this but here it goes:

`c1(tj+1) + c2tj +c3 + c4 = tj(c1+ c2) + (c1 + c3 + c4) = tj(c) + c = tj`

I would change it to

`c1(tj+1) + c2tj +c3 + c4 = tj(c1+ c2) + (c1 + MAX(c3,c4)) = tj(c) + c = tj`

As you pointed out, only c3 or c4 would run, so for the worst case we pick the one with more complexity (despite in this case both are constant).

```
How are you supposed to evaluate early return statements within an algorithm?
```

Complexity goes from the best case to the worst case (and an average case), you're evaluating the worst case. An early return would fit into the best case. Where the conditions supposed made it possible.

Comment: Hey Thanks... To be honest, I completely forgot that I had placed this question but I think your solution is spot on. Appreciate it!